# Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : attempt to use zero-length variable name R-Services on SQL Server

Tags: r, sql-server

I am using R Services on SQL Server. Following is an example of my code where I am computing Max of a column using R :

```
EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script @language = N'R' 
    , @script = N'
        r = order(InputDataSet$Id)
        InputDataSet = InputDataSet[r,]

        library(dplyr)

        OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet %>% group_by(Id) %>% mutate(
                                                   Max_Col1 = max(Col1, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                   Max_Col2 = max(Col2, na.rm = TRUE),
                                                   Max_Col3 = max(Col3, na.rm = TRUE),) %>%  slice(1)
          '
    , @input_data_1 = N'SELECT * FROM table_name;'
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Msg 39004, Level 16, State 20, Line 26
A 'R' script error occurred during execution of 'sp_execute_external_script' with HRESULT 0x80004004.
Msg 39019, Level 16, State 1, Line 26
An external script error occurred: 

Attaching package: 'dplyr'

The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  attempt to use zero-length variable name
Calls: source ... mutate -> mutate_ -> mutate_.tbl_df -> mutate_impl -> .Call

Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  Error in ScaleR.  Check the output for more information.
Calls: source -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> .Call
Execution halted
```

When I execute this same code on RStudio, it runs perfectly but gives error on the SQL Server. I do not understand what is this error about.

`R Version` on my SQL Server is: 3.2.2 (Fire Safety)
`packageVersion("dplyr")` on the SQL Server: 0.4.3

Comment: I see a `,` at the end `Max_Col3 = max(Col3, na.rm = TRUE),)` though it would work.  The error seems to be based on compatabiliity. of the versions.  The current `CRAN` version of `dplyr` is `0.8.3` on `R 3.6.2`

Comment: @akrun I am going to try upgrading the version of R on SQL Server and see how it goes

Comment: Can you check whether the Rstudio dplyr version that you run as working is the same as the one in sql server

Comment: @akrun I was using 3.6 version of R on Rstudio, but now I changed it to 3.2.2 and I get the same Error

Comment: Okay, so it must be some compatability with `dplyr::mutate`

Comment: Also, one more doubt, from the above code, I generate Col1, Col2, and Col3 also from a mutate command and insert those values in a table say `table1`, then again I in the above code I read the `InputDataSet` from the `table1`. Does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: Are you saying that `mutate` works when you create the columns?

Comment: Yes exactly, it works when I create the columns and insert it into the table, and now when I use those same mutated columns to generate Max or Min, it gives me the error

Comment: Try by removing the `max/min` and just do `mutate(newcol = Col1)` and see if there is an error.  Also, can you get the `str` printed. i.e. `str(InputDataSet)` from inside the script

Comment: If your object name is `table1` and is it stored in `InputDataSet <- "table1"` In that case, you may need `get(InputDataSet) %>% group_by(Id)`

Comment: If I remove `max`  and try to mutate it works !! @akrun Also, previously I tried to print the `head()` of `InputDataSet` and see, and it did print them all correctly

Comment: So, it must be an issue with `max` Perhaps the columns are not `numeric`. Try `Max_Col1 = max(as.numeric(Col1), na.rm = TRUE)`. If it is `factor`, then do `max(as.numeric(as.character(Col1)))`

Comment: Yess !! @akrun This worked, I cannot believe this was the error :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue would be based on the `class` of the column.  If it is not a `numeric`, convert to `numeric` and it should work

```
OutputDataSet <- InputDataSet %>%
                    group_by(Id) %>%
                    mutate(
                       Max_Col1 = max(as.numeric(as.character(Col1)), na.rm = TRUE),
                       Max_Col2 = max(as.numeric(as.character(Col2)), na.rm = TRUE),
                       Max_Col3 = max(as.numeric(as.character(Col3)), na.rm = TRUE),) %>%  
              slice(1)
```

---

If we are using the newer versions of `dplyr`

```
 InputDataSet %>%
         type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% # should change the type 
          group_by(Id) %>%
          mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Col")), list(Max = ~ max(., na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
          slice(1)
```

Comment: what if I have something like this `%>% mutate( Col4 = Col1[c(4)])` Why does this have a problem?

Comment: @KrushikaTapedia It shouldn't be a problem as you are selecting the 4th observation of 'Col1' and it should be recycled.  But, I am not sure how the behaviour was with the old version of `dplyr`.  May be you can `rep`licate i.e. `%>% mutate(Col4 = rep(Col1[4], n()))`

Comment: Thank you, I guess it's about having the right type of class then